# Duda sobre los gestores de contenido de páginas web

Tags: wordpress, joomla3

tengo una pregunta, si yo he creado mi pagina web con boostrap, y deseo colocarle un gestor de contenidos por ejemplo wordpres o jomla, estos CMS permiten les suba o cargue mi pagina, o por el contrario tiene o tiene que ser una plantilla de las que ellos manejan predeterminada y no una que yo haya hecho.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes ya todo hecho con boostrap, con wordpress puedes crear tu propio tema, es mas sencillo de lo que parece.

[Codex wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

en este enlace podras ver toda la documentacion para crear un tema de wordpress.

Comment: se te agradece el interés, pero en SO en español se valoran solo respuestas a preguntas con dudas sobre código en específico y esta pregunta es claro se basa en opiniones